# Auto increment version code on Generate signed APK only

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, version, auto-increment

I have successfully incremented version code. But I only want to increment it while I do generate signed apk from menu Build -> Generate signed APK. Following is my gradle code.

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
def versionPropsFile = file('version.properties')

if (versionPropsFile.canRead()) {
    def Properties versionProps = new Properties()

    versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(versionPropsFile))

    def code = versionProps['build.version'].toInteger() + 1

    versionProps['build.version']=code.toString()
    versionProps.store(versionPropsFile.newWriter(), null)

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test"
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode code
        versionName "1.1"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }
}
else {
    throw new GradleException("Could not read version.properties!")
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        //minifyEnabled false
        //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
}
dexOptions {
    incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    preDexLibraries = false
}}
```

And my version.properties file contains following info:
Minor=7
Branch=4
Major=10
build.version=73

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to do it by hooking up my code on assembleRelease gradle task. Got help from Tim's [blog](https://www.timroes.de/2013/09/22/handling-signing-configs-with-gradle/#comment-2780634226). Following is the code-

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application' 
android {
         compileSdkVersion 23
         buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

         def Properties versionProps = loadVersionFile()
         defaultConfig {
                      applicationId "com.test"
                      multiDexEnabled true
                      versionCode getCode(versionProps)
                      versionName getName(versionProps)
                      minSdkVersion 18
                      targetSdkVersion 23
        }
        signingConfigs {
                       release {
                                storeFile file(".../keys.jks")
                                storePassword "..."
                                keyAlias "..."
                                keyPassword "..."
                       }
       }


       buildTypes {
                   release {
                            signingConfig signingConfigs.release

                           //minifyEnabled false
                           //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
                  }
                  debug {
                            debuggable true
                  }
       }
       dexOptions {
            ...
       }
  }

def loadVersionFile() {
                    def versionPropsFile = file('version.properties')
                    def Properties versionProps
                    if (versionPropsFile.canRead()) {

                    versionProps = new Properties()
                    versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(versionPropsFile))

                    } else {
                          throw new GradleException("Could not read                                                 version.properties!")
                    }
                  return versionProps}

def getCode(Properties versionProps) {
         return versionProps['build.version'].toInteger()}

def getName(Properties versionProps) {
         return  versionProps['product.version']}


assembleRelease << {
         def versionPropsFile = file('version.properties')
         def code
         def Properties versionProps
         if (versionPropsFile.canRead()) {
                versionProps = new Properties()
                versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(versionPropsFile))
                code = versionProps['build.version'].toInteger() + 1
         } else {
             throw new GradleException("Could not read version.properties!")
         }

         versionProps['build.version'] = code.toString()
         versionProps.store(versionPropsFile.newWriter(), null)
         project.android.defaultConfig.versionCode code}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }

    maven {
        ...
    }
}}

dependencies {...}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Where are you created the version.properties file? Thanks.

Comment: In the root of project.

Comment: Great solution. Let me only one small clarification: `assemleRelease` can't be directly addressed when there are multiple projects with separated build files, because the task is dynamically created.
Instead, you have to use `afterEvaluate`!


afterEvaluate { project ->
    project.tasks.assembleRelease << {
        ...
    }
}

Comment: Even my previous extension wasn't enough, because the dynamic tasks  are available only when needed, so their existence also has to be checked:


afterEvaluate { project ->
if (project.tasks.findByName('assembleRelease')) {
    project.tasks.assembleRelease << {
        ...
    }
}
}

Answer (score 1):

To find out where you have to place the gradle.properties

Extract the whole signing config
First option is, to extract the whole signing config to a separate user file. Create a new property in your gradle.properties:

**MyProject.signing=/home/username/.signing/myproject**

MyProject doesn’t need to match any application names or so, you can in fact name the property whatever you like. Also if you’re on windows use \ instead of /.

Place your keystore at /home/username/.signing/myproject.keystore.

Now create a file name myproject.gradle in /home/username/.signing (create the folder if necessary). This file will contain your signing config, that should be used to sign the package. This could look like the following:

```
android {
  signingConfigs {
    release {
      storeFile file(project.property("MyProject.signing") + ".keystore")
      storePassword "mypassword"
      keyAlias "KeyAlias"
      keyPassword "mypassword"
    }
  }

  buildTypes {
    release {
      signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
  }
}
```

Now its time to configure the actual build.gradle file in the project you want to use this signing config. Just add the following lines to it:

```
if(project.hasProperty("MyProject.signing")
    && new File(project.property("MyProject.signing") + ".gradle").exists()) {
  apply from: project.property("MyProject.signing") + ".gradle";
}
```

Only extract some variables from file

```
project.ext {
  uploadRepo = 'http://....'
  uploadUser = 'myusername'
  uploadPass = 'mypass'
}
```

Now make sure you only use the variables if they are available by putting the configuration in the if after you loaded the file. So your build.gradle could look like that:

```
if(project.hasProperty("MyProject.signing")
    && new File(project.property("MyProject.signing") + ".gradle").exists()) {
  apply from: project.property("MyProject.signing") + ".gradle";

  // Configure stuff that relies on these variables
  uploadArchives {
    repositories.mavenDeployer {
      repository(url: uploadRepo) {
        authentication(userName: uploadUser, password: uploadPass)
      }
    }
    // .. whatever else you need ...
  }

}
```

Only extract some strings from file
Again add a path to your gradle.properties (let’s do it a full path this time):

**MyProject.properties=/home/username/.signing/myproject.properties**

```
if(project.hasProperty("MyProject.properties")
    && new File(project.property("MyProject.properties")).exists()) {

  Properties props = new Properties()
  props.load(new FileInputStream(file(project.property("MyProject.properties"))))

  android {
    signingConfigs {
      release {
        storeFile file(props['keystore'])
        storePassword props['keystore.password']
        // ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Just generate a plain properties file at **/home/username/.signing/myproject.properties:**

**keystore=/path/to/my/keystore
keystore.password=mypassword**